# Only a Set of shell script should execute a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script on `/usr/bin/myapp` and another 12 set of scripts on a diff folder (say `/opt/myapp`). I want a solution that only scripts from `/opt/myapp` can use or execute script in /usr/bin/myapp. This is to secure the script on `/usr/bin/myapp` and noone else except `/opt/myapp` should use it.

Any other solution is also accepted. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why storing the scripts in usr/bin at first instance, use a dedicated folder, why not a zip with a password.

Comment: I have passwords in /usr/bin

Comment: Then only yourself can execute those scripts anyway. Please add more details, not sure of your goal. It might be simpler than it looks like. The proper way is to use the @Martin solution, but this add a whole level of possible other issues.

Comment: @Dinesh : This looks like a design flaw. Basically, permission of executing scripts relies of having the read-permission of the script, and not of the location of the caller. Maybe it would be better, to code the 12 "scripts" as functions inside the "master script" instead of having them as separate files. In this case, only a really malevolent user could get his fingers at these twelve holy pieces of code, and he would need purposely break your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to grant "execute" permissions on the folder (or "read" and "execute" permissions on the scripts) only for a special group.

(Note that restricting "execute" permissions for the script alone is not enough, since read permissions are enough to execute a script with e.g. `sh /path/to/script`.)

Then you can grant the group permissions to the other scripts for instance via sudo (using some shell wrappers) or by writing your own binary wrappers.

Comment: Thx Martin for u r inputs .. Will try this and update you the same